# How to generate URLs in Symfony bundle's templates when prefixing all imported from bundle routes?

Tags: symfony, routes, prefix, bundles

I have a Symfony bundle which defines a controller and renders a few templates.
Routes are defined as annotations inside bundle's `routes.yaml`.

```
  * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="edit")
  * @Route("/new", name="new", defaults={"id" : null})
```

Then when I install the bundle into the app, I'm importing all routes from bundle's `routing.yaml` with prefixes. Like this:

```
admin_blog_controller:
    resource: '@BlogBundle/Resources/config/admin_routes.yaml'
    prefix: /admin/blog2
    name_prefix: admin.blog2.
```

Now I have templates in bundle 
and I need to  generate urls with unknown prefix.
(because prefixes are  defined outside of bundle).
I need to generate routes like this:
`{{ path('new') }}` or `{{ path('edit, {"id": blogId}) }}`
However routes are not found.

Is there a way to generate URLs inside bundle templates relative to bundle?
something like
`{{ path('@Bundle/new') }}` or `{{ path('@Bundle/edit, {"id": blogId}) }}`
so path could automatically detect and use prefixes of outter app?

Answer (score 2):

name your route unique names and then you can use it everywhere. something like:

`{{ path('acmeBundle_controllerName_actionName', {'id': Variable.id}) }}`

you can use 
`php bin/console debug:router  --env=dev` (symfony +3) or `php app/console debug:router  --env=prod` (symfony 2) to view your route names in your desired environment.

Answer (score -1):

Use `php bin/console debug:router`. You should see there all routes.